# Swift PageControl larger dot on current page

Tags: swift, uipagecontrol

I am attempting to scale dot of the current page to be larger than the dots which are not 'selected'.

I am using the scrollview delegate to ascertain which page is current.

At the moment there is no change to the size of the dot.

How would I go about achieving this?

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    var i = 0
    if(scrollView.contentOffset.x < scrollView.frame.width){

      pageControl.currentPage = 0
        pageControl.subviews.forEach {

            if(i == 0){
                print("Edit")
                $0.transform.scaledBy(x: 5, y: 5)
            }

            pageControl.layoutIfNeeded()
            i += 1
        }


    }else{
         pageControl.currentPage = 1
    }
}
```

Comment: You did not assign the result of `$0.transform.scaledBy(x: 5, y: 5)`. Maybe you mean `$0.transform = .identity.scaledBy(x: 5, y: 5)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scaling current dot of UIPageControl and keeping it centered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55060432/scaled-uipagecontrol-dot-isnt-centered)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIPageControl is not that customizable. Use a library like this one

[TAPageControl](https://github.com/TanguyAladenise/TAPageControl)

Is works the same way as UIPageControl and you can easily customize current and non current page dots by setting the properties dotImage and currentDotImage.