# Scaling current dot of UIPageControl and keeping it centered

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uipagecontrol

I've subclassed UIPageControl in order to have its current dot bigger.

```
class CustomPageControl: UIPageControl {
    override var currentPage: Int {
        didSet {
            updateDots()
        }
    }

    func updateDots() {
        let currentDot = subviews[currentPage]
        let largeScaling = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 3, y: 3)

        subviews.forEach {
            // apply the large scale of newly selected dot
            // restore the normal scale of previously selected dot
            $0.transform = $0 == currentDot ? largeScaling : .identity
        }
    }
}
```

But the result of the transform isn't centered (the red dot should be aligned with the others):
[image]

I've tried (on iOS 12):

- changing the `frame` or `center` of `currentDot` has no effect.
- changing the transform to include a `translatedBy(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat)` has no effect.
- changing the constraints [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51304362/1033581) is making the first dot jumping:

  ```
  currentDot.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
  currentDot.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor, constant: 0)
  currentDot.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor, constant: 0)
  ```

  [image]

Comment: Dot size is large then spec between two dots, try with small red dot.

Comment: @AtulParmar the positioning problem happens of course with any scale, large or small.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it finally working by rewriting *all* the subviews constraints by myself.

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/55063316/1033581
class DefaultPageControl: UIPageControl {

    override var currentPage: Int {
        didSet {
            updateDots()
        }
    }

    override func sendAction(_ action: Selector, to target: Any?, for event: UIEvent?) {
        super.sendAction(action, to: target, for: event)
        updateDots()
    }

    private func updateDots() {
        let currentDot = subviews[currentPage]
        let largeScaling = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 3.0, y: 3.0)
        let smallScaling = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)

        subviews.forEach {
            // Apply the large scale of newly selected dot.
            // Restore the small scale of previously selected dot.
            $0.transform = $0 == currentDot ? largeScaling : smallScaling
        }
    }

    override func updateConstraints() {
        super.updateConstraints()
        // We rewrite all the constraints
        rewriteConstraints()
    }

    private func rewriteConstraints() {
        let systemDotSize: CGFloat = 7.0
        let systemDotDistance: CGFloat = 16.0

        let halfCount = CGFloat(subviews.count) / 2
        subviews.enumerated().forEach {
            let dot = $0.element
            dot.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(dot.constraints)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                dot.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: systemDotSize),
                dot.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: systemDotSize),
                dot.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor, constant: 0),
                dot.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor, constant: systemDotDistance * (CGFloat($0.offset) - halfCount))
            ])
        }
    }
}
```

System constants in the code (7.0 and 16.0) are respectively the size and the distance found for a default UIPageControl dot on iOS 12.

[image: result]

Comment: I tried this, and while it works (although offset to the left), I get error messages on the console: "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints." with more than 1 page and there are two centerX NSLayoutConstraints listed. When I print the constraints on `dot` before removing them, there are only two - and none of them show the centerX constraint.  My pageControl is added to the UI in storyboard, but I also tried adding one programmatically but still get the errors.  the component looks like it's doing the right thing to the user, but the constraint violations it's throwing worry me.

Comment: Improvements welcome, @ChanchalRaj. My solution was good for iOS 12 and iOS 13.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solution proposed by [Cœur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1033581/c%C5%93ur) in Swift 5 and Xcode 11 and it works fine with a few notes:

- The PageControl element in IB/Storyboard has to be positioned with constraints.
- The dots are slightly off-center but it can be quickly fixed by changing the constant of the last constraint to `systemDotDistance * ( CGFloat($0.offset) - (halfCount - 0.5))`.
- If the `updateConstraints` override is never called, you might need to call `self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()` in the view controller.